# PyQt4 isChecked() method

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am using Qt Designer to build a UI. In Qt Designer, in the Signal/Slot editor I set up the following:

Sender: radioButton,
Signal: toggled(bool),
Receiver: checkbox,
Slot: setChecked(bool)

When I run my .py file, as expected, when I select radioButton with the mouse in the user interface, checkbox is checked.

However. if I add a button that calls a function, which includes the following code:

print(checkBox.isChecked())

The boolean value I get in return is 'False', even though the checkbox is visibly checked.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the

checkBox.isChecked()

method was in the wrong place. It was checked whenever the program was run (where the checkbox was empty) but not afterwards. As it turns out, the signal is generated via mouse after the program is run.

So I added the method to the function that checks the state of the checkbox after a button is clicked.

Please be merciful in grading this post thread :). New to stackoverflow.